# Replace String Contain multiple string in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Shipping address to persons contain multiple text inside it , for example in this 4 Rows of consumer address.

```
     |         Address Line                 |
     |--------------------------------------|
     |APARTMENT 5800 springfield GARDENS CIR|
     |--------------------------------------|
     |APT 5800 springfield GARDENS CIR      |
     |--------------------------------------|
     |2567 south pay street                 |
     |--------------------------------------|
     |Office 222 Market , VA 048946         |
```

How can i add another column that contain certain character such as `Address Line` contain "Apartment" or "APT" will become "Apartment" and `Address Line` contain "Street" will become "Household" , `Address Line` contain "Office" will become "Office building" and "Unknown" for `Address Line` not included.

This is the desired table after the query included with `PostgreSql`

```
         |         Address Line                 |      Location      |
         |--------------------------------------|--------------------|
         |APARTMENT 5800 springfield GARDENS CIR|   Apartement       |
         |--------------------------------------|--------------------|
         |APT 5800 springfield GARDENS CIR      |   Apartement       |
         |--------------------------------------|--------------------|
         |2567 south pay street                 |   Household        |
         |--------------------------------------|--------------------|
         |Office 222 Market , VA 048946         |   Office building  |
         |--------------------------------------|--------------------|
```

This is my query :

```
 SELECT ORDER_TABLE.guest_email,
        CASE WHEN ORDER_SHIPPINGADDRESS.LINE1 IN ('Apartement', 'apt') Then 'Apartement'
        WHEN ('street') then 'household'
        WHEN ('Office') then 'Office Building'
        ELSE 'Location Unknown' END as Location
```

My trial so far by using `Case When` however it ended error like this

`ERROR: argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type record`

Are there any functions that can do the desired table above? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should repeat `ORDER_SHIPPINGADDRESS.LINE1 IN`in each WHEN

```
SELECT ORDER_TABLE.guest_email,
    CASE WHEN ORDER_SHIPPINGADDRESS.LINE1 IN ('Apartement', 'apt') Then 'Apartement'
         WHEN ORDER_SHIPPINGADDRESS.LINE1 IN ('street') then 'household'
         WHEN ORDER_SHIPPINGADDRESS.LINE1 IN ('Office') then 'Office Building'
    ELSE 'Location Unknown' END as Location
```